# Change the clipboard style in email

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, clipboard

I have a macro that paste the clipboard in an email but it retains the original format of the text.

I can't make the pasted text to be in a normal format or quick style normal. First I put a text, then paste the clipboard and then another text.

I want the clipboard content to have the same style as the other texts or just normal.

```
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
 With OutMail
     .To = ""
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = ""
     Set olInsp = .GetInspector
     Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
     Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
     oRng.collapse 1
     .Display
     OutMail.HTMLBody = textB & OutMail.HTMLBody
     oRng.Paste
     OutMail.HTMLBody = textA & OutMail.HTMLBody

 End With
```

i have tried with :

```
     'oRng.Font.Bold = True ' changes the font but not the style
     'oRng.Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)" ' changes the font but not the style
     'oRng.Font.Color = vbRed ' changes the font but not the style
     'oRng.Style = 1 ' not working
     'With oRng.ParagraphFormat ' changes the spacing but not the style
     '.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast 
     '.LineSpacing = 10
     'End With
     '.BodyFormat = 1 ' not working
```

[image]

And this is the code:

```
Sub aaaaa()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim StrBdA As String
Dim StrBdB As String
Dim lll As String
Dim myString As String
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Object
Dim sourceWS As Object

StrBdA = "<br> <br>" & "text" _
                 & "<br> <br>" & "text" _
                 & "<br> <br>" & "text" _
                 & "<br>" & "1." & "text</b>" _
                 & "<br>" & "2." & "text" _
                 & "<br>" & "3." & "text" & "<br> <br>"  


StrBdB = "<br> <br>" & "text." _
                 & "<br>" & "text" _
                 & "<br>" & "text:" _
                 & "<br>" & "<a link1>link1</a>" _
                 & "<br>" & "<a link2>link2</a>" _
                 & "<br> <br>" & "text" & "<br> <br>"

     On Error Resume Next
     Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     On Error GoTo 0

     Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
     With OutMail
         OutMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh
         .To = ""
         '.CC = ""
         .BCC = ""
         .Subject = ""

         Set olInsp = .GetInspector
         Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
         Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
         oRng.collapse 1
         .Display
         OutMail.HTMLBody = StrBdB & OutMail.HTMLBody
          oRng.Paste
          oRng.Font.Bold = True
         OutMail.HTMLBody = StrBdA & OutMail.HTMLBody
     End With
     Set OutMail = Nothing
     Set OutApp = Nothing
     Set olInsp = Nothing
     Set wdDoc = Nothing
     Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel there is `.PasteSpecial` for this. I can only find code related to Excel though, but you can try it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx

Comment: `oRng.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)`

Comment: Thank you for your answers but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: i have tried with          SendKeys "{^}{A}", True         SendKeys "{+}{^}{N}", True            But it doesn't work

Comment: Either you are yourself confused or you are confusing the programme. From where your clipboard content is coming? manual copying ? because your code don't show from where your clipboard content is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried something based on this. I initially made it for Word but is working fine with some modification in my Outlook 2010

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMailBodyNormal()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olEmail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "Movies Report"
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range(0, 0)
        oRng.Paste
        oRng.Style = "Normal"
        .Display
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to formate the only clipboard content, It is not straight forward. I generally prefer opening a new hidden word instance and formate accordingly and close it.

Comment: THIS IS WORKING. Thank you very very very very very much.